# Need help creating an MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a couple tables I've created in Access.

```
              [Projects]                                       [Assigned]
   [Project Name]  |  [Billable]     [Project Name]  |  [Employee]  |  [Date]   |  [Hours Worked]
        CX111      |    False             LM565      |     Bill     | 1/3/2014  |        8
        LM565      |    True              CX111      |     Zach     | 1/3/2014  |        3
         ...       |    ...               LM565      |     John     | 1/5/2014  |        5 
        AA888      |    True              AA888      |     Bill     | 1/25/2014 |        5
                                          LM565      |     Terry    | 2/6/2014  |        7
```

I need to create a report which checks to see if each project is Billable. It then needs to add up all of the [Hours Worked] for all billable project for the month and then display the total hours in the report.

The above would display

```
                        [Billable Hours for the Month]
                       [Month]       |  [Total Billable Hours]
                     January 2014    |          18
                     February 2014   |           7
```

I am new to Access, and while I know I need to use an 'If' statement to check to see if the project is [Billable], it would appear that I would also need to use some kind of loop to sum all of the totals from the two tables. I am not sure how to create loops, or how to check and write information from two separate tables.

Thanks for any help you might be able to give.
-Crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to use loops or If statements/functions. The following query should provide the totals you need:

```sql
SELECT 
    YEAR(Assigned.[Date]) AS Yr,
    MONTH(Assigned.[Date]) AS Mo,
    SUM(Assigned.[Hours Worked]) AS Hrs
FROM
    Assigned
    INNER JOIN
    Projects
        ON Projects.[Project Name] = Assigned.[Project Name]
WHERE Projects.Billable
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Assigned.[Date]),
    MONTH(Assigned.[Date])
```